# Changing http request parameter name dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a http json request param like

```
const requestPayload = {
 'requestType': 'getPost',
 'dateSelectionFrom': '2018-02-26'
}
```

I need to change the `dateSelectionFrom` parameter based on user selection from the dropdown. If the user select `dateSelectionTo` it should send as `dateSelectionTo`.

Comment: you should post the code of your template and at least the method for forming and sending the request

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows

I am assuming you are preparing your json while submitting the form
otherwise, you can also try change event for select box

In HTML

```
<div>   
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedDevice" name="sel2">
    <option value="dateSelectionFrom">dateSelectionFrom</option>
    <option value="dateSelectionTo">dateSelectionTo</option>   </select>

  <input type="button" value="Test" (click)="click()">


</div>
```

In your ts file

```
selectedDevice: string;
  requestPayload: any;
  click() {
    this.requestPayload = new Array();
    this.requestPayload['requestType'] = 'getPost';
    this.requestPayload[this.selectedDevice] = '2018-02-26';
    // You can send your request here
    console.log(this.requestPayload);

  }
```